# How could I implement a dialogue box message if two columns have equal values in their rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I have worksheets that are distributed to managers. Columns A:O are locked (protected sheet), but columns P:T are editable with a few drop down validation lists.

If a manager inputs data in column S (cell S2) and their selection off the drop down list = the same value as what's in column O (cell O2), then I want a dialogue box to show that they cannot input the same value.

I was thinking something like this:

**rng 1 = column O, rng 2 = column S**

```
Dim rng1 As range, rng2 As range
lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

Set rng1 = Range("O2:O" & lastrow)
Set rng2 = Range("S2:S" & lastrow)

If rng1.value = rng2.value Then
    -dialogue box "You cannot input the same %"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more immediate, you can use the `Worksheet_Change()` event to make the dialog show immediately when the value is entered - and clear the value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim watchRng As Range
    Set watchRng = Me.Columns("S")

    If Not Intersect(Target, watchRng) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Value = Me.Cells(Target.Row, "O").Value Then

            Application.EnableEvents = False

            MsgBox "You cannot input the same %"
            Target.ClearContents

            Application.EnableEvents = True

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

This need's to be placed in the **Worksheet's Code Module** for this to work properly.

Comment: How would this work if my code is populating a new workbook with every manager on the master file? Where would I paste this if the worksheet is constantly opening and closing to a new set of data?